# Canvas width of 100% of viewport or parent div

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to do 100% Canvas to fit either viewport or parent div.
Here is what I have:

```html
<canvas id="mapDrawingCanvas" width="600px" height="600px" style="position:fixed;"></canvas>
 <script>
  console.log("width of canvas is: "+$("#mapDrawingCanvas").width());
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mapDrawingCanvas');
    canvas.selection = false;
    canvas.width = viewportWidth;
    canvas.height = viewportHeight;
    console.log(canvas.width);

});
```

But the size of canvas is 600px as defined in html. My console log shows this:

```html
width of canvas is: 600
1440
```

So I know that my javascript runs last, therefore I expect the canvas size to be 1440px not 600px.

Also I tried to change .ready to .load or window.load, but it didn't helped.

Comment: `canvas = document.getElementById('mapDrawingCanvas');` then after you resize you can overwrite canvas with the Fabric object `canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mapDrawingCanvas');`

Comment: @RobertParham, wow, it helped, thanks

Comment: happeh to halp.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly changing the attribute value for canvas before binding `fabric` works fine.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m7y9uo6x/2/

```
<canvas id="mapDrawingCanvas" width="600px" height="600px" style="position:fixed;"></canvas>
<script>
  console.log("width of canvas is: " + $("#mapDrawingCanvas").width());

</script>


 var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
 var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
 debugger;
 var canvasElem = $("#mapDrawingCanvas");
 canvasElem.attr("width", viewportWidth);
 canvasElem.attr("height", viewportHeight);
 canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mapDrawingCanvas', {
   backgroundColor: 'rgb(100,100,200)'
 });
 canvas.selection = false;
 console.log("new width" + canvas.width);
```